# Handling browser closing when tests are done

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I'm using Capybara with the Selenium webdriver in my testing suite. I've noticed that when all tests are complete, Selenium closes the browser by binding to `at_exit`. However, this causes an issue for my web application displays a "Are you sure you want to navigate away" dialog `onunload` (Please don't judge. This is an intranet application and the users specifically requested it.). So when the tests are done my Cucumber scenario fails (even though all my steps pass) because there was an unhandled Javascript `confirm` dialog. Is there any way to bind after Selenium tries to close the browser and accept the dialog?

**Update**

I believe I have found the issue with this. It appears that after each test, Capybara resets the browser by clearing all cookies and navigating to about:blank. This is what is causing the `onbeforeunload` dialog to open (not `browser.quit()`). I'm cross posting on the Capybara mailing list to try to get help on this and will post anything I find here.

Comment: Whilst I'm not entirely familiar with the bindings you're using, does the `driver.switch_to_alert() alert.confirm()` (for the python version) not work for you?

Comment: That's what I need to do, I just can't figure out the appropriate place to do it. It appears that either Capybara or Cucumber is closing the browser when the test scenario is complete. That's when I need to switch to the alert and accept it.

Comment: Is there access to a 'tearDown` method? Could you put in a `try/catch` there perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking for. There's an `at_exit` method that Capybara binds to in which it calls `driver.quit()`. But I need to be inside of the `driver.quit()` method because this is where the `confirm` dialog gets popped and where the exception is thrown if I don't handle it.

Comment: With the Python bindings `driver.quit()` just quits, no matter what is open. I've used it on pages with `onunload` bringing up a prompt. No problem. The [documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#quit%28%29) also says that `quit` "closes every associated window" (the prompt is a window too, so it should be closed). To me, this suggests a bug in the Ruby bindings, or something else interfering with Selenium.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if it's Capybara or what, but `driver.quit()` doesn't work for me. I'm still getting `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError`

Comment: Before writing my earlier comment, I performed a quick test just to make sure I was not forgetting something special I did in my test suites. You probably already know that jsfiddle.net prompts you if you entered any text, did not save, and quit or close the page. I wrote a 11-line Selenium script (using Python) that would open jsfiddle.net, pause 2 seconds, enter "asdf", pause 2 seconds, and then call `driver.quit()`. It worked flawlessly. You could try the same with Ruby. If this works then the problem is not with Selenium. If it does not work then Selenium is the issue.

Comment: @Louis Great idea. I tried this with JSFiddle and confirmed that I'm getting the same issue. Still not sure if it's Capybara or Selenium, but at least it doesn't appear and issue with my site or test procedure.

Comment: @Kyle You say you're still not sure whether the issue is Selenium or Capybara. You should try removing Capybara from the equation and see if the issue still occurs. If it still occurs, I'd suggest trying with different browsers to see if you can narrow it down to a specific browser. I've been there and done that myself (except I was using Python and I was not using an equivalent of Capybara) and ended up submitting about 6 patches to the Selenium project.

Comment: @Louis It's definitely Capybara. See my update on the OP. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the OP update it appears that Capybara navigates to about:blank as the end of each Cucumber scenario. After talking with jnicklas from the Capybara team it appears that the best way to handle this is to implement a Cucumber `after` handler which navigates away before Capybara tries to and handle the alert there.

```
After do
  # after each test navigate away before Capybara tries to so that we can appropriately handle the onbeforeunload dialog
  if @browser
    begin
      @browser.navigate.to("about:blank")
      @browser.switch_to.alert.accept
    rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoAlertPresentError
      # No alert was present. Don't need to do anything
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to switch context `at_exit` and accept or dismiss the alert. Something like this

```
at_exit do
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
  #or
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.dismiss
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried setting up my own `at_exit` method (which appears to run before Capybara's `at_exit`. The problem is that I can't accept or dismiss the alert until the browser is closed. If I try to call `quit` and then accept the alert this doesn't work either (alert goes away and then comes back).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a unit test framework like JUnit or TestNG, then what I do is use Configuration annoations like @AfterTest  or @AfterClass  to quit the browser.   This way, while the test is running the browser is always up.  It's not until the @Test block is finished that the test case will close the browser instance.

If you are using Ruby, I assume there is something similar to this.

Answer (score -1):

Like it was mentioned, calling driver.Quit() should solve the problem, but if the pop-up window is causing an issue that prevents the browser from closing, then eliminate the instance. A simple solution is to wrap your test inside of a using clause.

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver())
{
    //Perform your test
    driver.Quit(); 
}
```